# perl script select wireless lan network

Tags: windows, perl, networking

I have a perl script that log's in to a wireless form to authenticate the problem is I need to ensure it connects to the correct wireless lan automatically.
How can I script this behavior to select the wireless lan perhaps based on SSID?
I am on windows 7 but ideally if there is a module that can make this portable?

Answer (score 0):

The same way you managed to get it to log in?

Comment: yes basically select a specific wireless network from a script